# How can a Mithral Golem move at double speed and full attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I am reading the description of the [Mithral Golem](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-mithral/) on d20pfsrd.com. In the description of the *Quickness (Ex)* special ability, it states:

> A mithral golem is incredibly quick. It can take an extra move action during its turn each round. This means it can move up to double its speed and still make a full attack.

This doesn't make any sense, since making a Full Attack would use Golem's full-round action, and the bonus move action left over would only allow it to move its normal speed, 50ft. So far as I can see the Golem does not have any other abilities which would allow it to move more. Why does the description state it can move up to double speed and still full attack?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It must be a misprint. At [paizo.com](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/golem.html#golem,-mithral) it reads:

> A mithral golem is incredibly quick. It can take an extra move action during its turn each round. This means it can move **up to its speed** and still make a full attack.

Comment: That's interesting. Could the error be copied from from a mistake in the earlier version of Paizo's publishing or was it somehow introduced to the d20pfsrd.com site? I looked at the [errata](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/resources) for Bestiary 2, but the only adjustment to the Mithral golem is correcting its AC to include a dodge bonus, so it doesn't seem like the error was published by Paizo.

Comment: @Carcer I'm not an expert in pathfinder. The ability description was strangely formulated in the SRD, a misprint was one of my immediate guesses. So I decided to check the developers site. I can say nothing about any previous version.